# ActivityNotFoundException while Decleared in Manifest

Tags: android

I have a strange problem, I have Declared my FileChooserActivity in my manifest like this:

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="com.lifemate.lmmessenger.LMApplication">

    <activity
        android:name="com.lifemate.lmmessenger.main.MessengerLOCR"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>


   <provider android:name="com.lifemate.lmmessenger.database.ContactsProvider" 

     android:authorities="com.lifemate.lmmessenger.database.provider.contactsprov">
    </provider>



       <receiver android:name="Receiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.lifemate.lmmessenger.Receiver" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

<activity
 android:name="com.lifemate.lmmessenger.fileviews.FileChooserActivity"
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_chooser"
 android:enabled="@bool/use_activity"
 android:exported="true"
 android:label="@string/choose_file" >
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
 </intent-filter>
</activity>


 </application>
```

I'm sure that the adress is true,but in run time I receive ClassNotFoundException, am I doing some thing wrong guys?

the Class:

```
 package com.lifemate.lmmessenger.fileviews;

 public class FileChooserActivity extends Activity {

String path =null ;
String type = null;
ImageView iv;
private static final String TAG = "FileChooserExampleActivity";

 private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 6384; // onActivityResult request
                                               // code

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_chooser);
    iv =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewThumb);
    // Create a simple button to start the file chooser process
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChooseImage);
  //  button.setText(R.string.choose_file);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Display the file chooser dialog
            showChooser();
        }
    });

}


//http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html
public void SaveImage(View v){


    System.out.println(path);
    String Path = path;

 if(path!=null){



         String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path);
         if (extension != null) {
             MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
             type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

             Log.i("MIME",type);
         }
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result",Path);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
    Log.i("Image",path);
    finish();

 }else{
     Toast.makeText(FileChooserActivity.this,"You Havent Chose any Thing Yet...",   
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }


 }

 public void convertsize(){
File file=new File("storage/sdcard/Pictures/reza22.png");
File file2=new File("storage/sdcard/Pictures/reza2.jpg");  

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("storage/sdcard/Pictures/reza2.jpg");  
Bitmap bmpCompressed = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 635,479, true);  

 FileOutputStream out = null;
 try {
out = new FileOutputStream(file);
bmpCompressed.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); 

 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
try{
   out.close();
 } catch(Throwable ignore) {}
 }

 }



  public Bitmap decodeFile(File input){
   try {
    //Decode image size
    File file=new File("storage/sdcard/Pictures/reza22.jpg");

    BitmapFactory.Options o11 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o11.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(input),null,o11);

    //The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE=400;

    //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int scale=1;
    while(o11.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o11.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
        scale*=2;

    //Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o22 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o22.inSampleSize=scale;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(input), null, o22);
    Bitmap bmpCompressed = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(input.toString(), o22);
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
       out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       bmpCompressed.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); 

    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       try{
           out.close();
       } catch(Throwable ignore) {}
    }

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
  return null;
  }



 private void showChooser() {
    // Use the GET_CONTENT intent from the utility class
    Intent target = FileUtils.createGetContentIntent();
    // Create the chooser Intent
    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(
            target, getString(R.string.chooser_title));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // The reason for the existence of aFileChooser
    }
 }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE:
            // If the file selection was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    // Get the URI of the selected file
                    final Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Uri = " + uri.toString());
                    try {
                        // Get the file path from the URI
                        final String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);
                        this.path=path;


                     String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path);
                     if (extension != null) {
                         MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                         type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                         if(type.startsWith("image")){
                            System.out.println("Loading Image into iv");

  Picasso.with(FileChooserActivity.this).load(path).resize(40, 
  40).centerCrop().into(iv);
                         }
                     }


                        Toast.makeText(FileChooserActivity.this,
                                "File Selected: " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("FileSelectorTestActivity", "File select error", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

here the full error:

```
  07-01 21:35:17.779: E/AndroidRuntime(874): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-01 21:35:17.779: E/AndroidRuntime(874): Process: com.lifemate.lmmessenger, PID: 874
 07-01 21:35:17.779: E/AndroidRuntime(874): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
  Unable to find explicit activity class   
 {com.lifemate.lmmessenger/com.lifemate.lmmessenger.fileviews.FileChooserActivity};  
 have 
 you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
 07-01 21:35:17.779: E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at 
 android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
 07-01 21:35:17.779: E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at 
 android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
 07-01 21:35:17.779: E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at 
 android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
 07-01 21:35:17.779: E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at 
 android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
 07-01 21:35:17.779: E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at     
 android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment
 (FragmentActivity.java:854     )
 07-01 21:35:17.779: E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at 
 android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:889)
 07-01 21:35:17.779: E/AndroidRuntime(874):     at    
 com.lifemate.lmmessenger.tabs.GamesFragment$1.onClick(GamesFragment.java:380)
```

Comment: post your code please...

Comment: no idea what does it have to do with the code, but posted the code, thanks alot ^^

Comment: Please also post the exact error message.

Comment: this time it returned ANFE !

Answer (score 0):

You have a package problem.

Show us the beginning of your Manifest…

It should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      package="com.your.complete.package"
      android:versionCode="104"
      android:versionName="3.00.062513">
```

and then your activities…

```
 <application
  android:name=".YourApp"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:theme="@style/YourTheme">

<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.LauncherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
```

Notice the name of the activity:

**.ui.activities.LauncherActivity**

^ see the dot?

That means that my activity is located at:

*com.your.complete.package.ui.activities.LauncherActivity.java*

According to your manifest and the error message, seems like you have the full path and therefore your activity is being searched at:

```
com.lifemate.lmmessenger.com.lifemate.lmmessenger.fileviews.FileChooserActivity
```

Change it for

```
.fileviews.FileChooserActivity
```

Comment: Negative, for some reason it got fixed by removing this field:

     android:enabled="@bool/use_activity"